# HTTP URL Blacklist driver

Tags: http, url, winapi, driver, blacklist

how to code HTTP URL blacklisting driver for both XP and Vista/7?
I need it for special software for schools

any ideas about HTTPS or VPN? I was thinking about firefox, IE,... extension. Not bulletproof, but better than nothing. It's just school.

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework?  What the heck do you mean by "driver"?

Comment: This should be done by a DNS server.

Comment: driver.. or filter or what (I don't see into Windows network stack) - something that will connect into network stack and will parse HTTP request packets and block them if necessary
DNS is not suitable for this. There also computers in school administration, which must be without any restriction
My idea is to filter traffic at computers, some schools may not have suitable infrastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winsock supports a [Service Provider Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which is probably where you'll want to install your "driver". You'll (probably) want/need to install your provider as a "filter" that depends on the existing providers, but all traffic is forced to go though your provider between winsock itself, and the existing providers.

Unless you're going to deploy this on a large number of campuses or something on that order, it'll almost certainly be substantially cheaper to do the filtering in the router(s) instead.

Comment: "it'll almost certainly be substantially cheaper to do the filtering in the router" - yes - and dansguardian is free to try, works well and is ridiculously cheap.